# bootstrap-vuejs pagination-nav component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm using `boostrap-vuejs` and I'm fetching data using axios, this is the response which i plan to use in pagination:-

```
pagination {
    current_page:1
    last_page:5
    next_page_url:"http://papp.test/api/citizens?page=2"
    per_page:10
    prev_page_url:null
}
```

using the component `pagination-nav`

```
<b-pagination-nav :number-of-pages="pagination.last_page" :limit="pagination.per_page"/>
```

How can I render the `pagination.next_page_url` and `pagination.prev_page_url` in component `pagination-nav` because I'm confused how to use the `linkGen` and `pageGen` based on [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination-nav/#bar).